# Hide developer settings from menu

Tags: settings

Most of us will know that tapping "build number" a few times in "about device" gives us access to developer settings.

Is there a way to reverse this, and hide developer settings from the menu without doing a factory reset?

Comment: Android 4.4.x isn't there a switch at the top once in the developer options, on/off?

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't hide it from the menu, it just switches it off

Answer (score 2):

There're two methods to hide it completely:

**1. factory reset**

This should be clear, but if you need more info comment.

**2. OTA Update**

When your device manufacturer releases an update and you install this update the developer settings get hidden.

**other possible solutions**

- maybe on your device you can clear the settings app data and cache. But this doesn't work always
- You can toggle the developer settings in the upper right off, but the settings doesn't get hidden

Sorry but there aren't any other possibilities yet. Maybe you can say what device it is and I can help you.

Comment: I've tried clearing settings app data and cache, that doesn't work. I know I can toggle it to off but I want to hide it from the menu.

Comment: Ok, but as I said, there are only two ways to do this

Comment: I'm using a custom ROM. OTA update won't have any effect on dev settings.

Comment: Then factory reset and reflash the ROM from scratch. The above answer has 2 ways. You'll have to do one of them, and since you can't do an OTA, the other is the way to go.